# Authentication failure: Login page returns DoesNotEXist for users already in the database

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

I am trying to grasp Python Django. I'm trying to make a bank system  web application. I can register users. These users then are automatically logged in. However, after logout I cannot login the same user again. The page tells me the user does not exist

I have tried to play around with my backends.py in the terminal. when i run

$ user=User.objects.get(pk=1)
$ user

it returns the user with the id in the database. However it doesnt work with the login page. Kindly help, I have been stuck for a week.

models.py:

```py
     class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, account_no, password=None, **extra_fields):
            """
                   Create and save a user with the given account_no and password.
                   """
            user = self.model(account_no=account_no, **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
            return user

        def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
            """
            Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
            """
            user = self.create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)
            user.is_admin = True
            user.save(using=self._db)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
            extra_fields.setdefault('account_no', False)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
            return user


    class User(AbstractUser):
        username = models.CharField(
            ('username'), max_length=30, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
        contact_no = models.IntegerField(unique=False, null=True,blank=True)
        account_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(
            unique=True,
            validators=[
                MinValueValidator(1000000000),
                MaxValueValidator(9999999999)
            ])
        balance = models.DecimalField(
            default=0,
            max_digits=12,
            decimal_places=2
        )
        GENDER_CHOICE = (
            ("M", "Male"),
            ("F", "Female"),
        )
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
        birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
        postal_code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
        picture = models.ImageField(
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            upload_to='account_pictures/',
        )

        objects = UserManager()

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'account_no'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', ]

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.full_name)


    views.py:

    def login_view(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                account_no = form.cleaned_data.get('account_no')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(account_no=account_no, password=password)
                login(request, user, backend='accounts.backends.ModelBackend')
                messages.success(request, 'Welcome, {}!'.format(user.full_name))
                return redirect("home")

            context = {"form": form,
                       "title": "Load Account Details",
                       }

            return render(request, "accounts/login.html", context)


    backends.py:

    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    User = get_user_model()


    class ModelBackend(object):
        def authenticate(self, request, account_no=None, password=None):
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(account_no=account_no)
                if user and user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None

        def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
forms.py:

    class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
        account_no = forms.IntegerField(label="Account Number")
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
            account_no = self.cleaned_data.get("account_no")
            password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

            if account_no and password:
                user = authenticate(account_no=account_no, password=password)
                if not user:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Account Does Not Exist.")
                if not user.check_password(password):
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Password Does not Match.")
                if not user.is_active:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Account is not Active.")

            return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

The user that has been registered should be able to login. The program keeps denying registered users from logging in.

Comment: Check `User.objects.get(account_no=account_no)`. Is `account_no` after `=` value is string or not

Comment: @shafik account_no after= value is not string. It is an integer- account number

Comment: pick a account_no from db then check it on python console

Comment: kindly elaborate on what I should check for

Comment: Look at your database table then in terminal query with an `account_no` like `User.objects.get(account_no=123456789)`

Comment: I have run the following command:
>>> from accounts.models import User
>>> user=User.objects.get(account_no=1000000000)
>>> user
<User: Kenaz Otieno>
>>>

Comment: Now in modelbackend check which account_no you pass by `print(account_no)`  then check is this account_no exists in database

Comment: how exactly do u pass print to a backends please?

Comment: class ModelBackend(object):
        def authenticate(self, request, account_no=None, password=None):
            try: print(account_no)

Comment: then how do I run the command to print the account_no?

Comment: This value you show in the terminal where you Django server run. Or if you can debug, then debug this. Debugging is the best practice.

Comment: I am afraid I dont understand this clearly. Anyway, thanks so much for your help

Comment: I think I have an idea of what is wrong with my code @shafik     I have not subclassed Django's AuthenticationForm in my forms.py. Hence it doesnt recognize account_no as a field for authentication?